# Express the negation of the following statements WITHOUT using the negation symbol

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> 1. $\forall x\, (-2 < x < 3)$
> 2. $\forall x\, (0 \le x < 5)$
> 3. $\exists x\,  (-4 \le x \le 1)$
> 4. $\exists x\, (-5 < x < -1)$
> 5. $\forall x \exists y \, (x^2 < y)$

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

*Context* - I had difficulty solving these problems and I thought I would get insight from smart people online. I couldn't find solutions for these questions elsewhere, so I decided to ask for help here since I wasn't even sure where to begin.

I might have figured out the first one.

1. $\exists x\, (-2\geq x\vee \ x\geq3)$
2. $\exists x\, (0\gt x\vee \ x\geq5)$
3. $\forall x\, (-4\gt x\vee \ x\gt-1)$
4. $\forall x\, (-5\geq x\vee \ x\geq-1)$
5. $\exists x\ \forall y\, (x^2\ge y)$

Comment: What are your thoughts for how to proceed with the first one?

Comment: Yes, please explain where you’re stuck. Do you know what the symbols mean? Can you write the first statement in plain English without symbols?

Comment: This is just a new concept that we began studying. Due to some time constraints, I was unable to delegate more of my time to focus on learning these concepts. I just know the basics such as the symbols (and even they are kinda new, not gonna lie). ∀ = for all or for every, ∃ = there exists. ∀x ∃y = "for every x there exists y" (I believe)

Comment: The first in simple english reads "For every $x$ we have that $-2<x<3$."  Think about what the opposite of that would be.  If we knew that it wasn't the case that *every* $x$ was in that range, then that must mean that there was some $x$ outside of that range.

Comment: With your edit, yes you have it correct for the first problem, and the next few should be very similar.  As a typesetting note, use `\geq` and `\leq` to make the symbols $\geq$ and $\leq$ respectively, and use `\vee` and `\wedge` to make $\vee$ and $\wedge$ respectively.  See more MathJax and $\LaTeX$ tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Just pay close attention to the order of symbols for the last one and recognize that $\forall x \exists y$ means something different than $\exists y \forall x$

Comment: You should probably take this time to study these concepts so that you can ask a specific question. As it stands, it appears that you are saying that you have no time so we should do your homework for you. That's not an assertion, it's just what it looks like.

Comment: @JMoravitz is giving you good general advice. Rewrite these formal statements in English. Then write their negations in English. Then convert to formal logical statements if you must (but that's not a the best way to write understandable mathematics).

Comment: I apologize if that's what it looked like. I will admit I haven't read the rules about posting homework questions until just now, so I apologize if I came out rude telling people to do my assignments for me. I managed to finish these problems and will update an answer asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\exists x\, (-2\geq x\vee \ x\geq3)$
2. $\exists x\, (0\gt x\vee \ x\geq5)$
3. $\forall x\, (-4\gt x\vee \ x\gt-1)$
4. $\forall x\, (-5\geq x\vee \ x\geq-1)$
5. $\exists x\ \forall y\, (x^2\ge y)$